# Macro Triggers when cell value changes - using 'Worksheet_Change' vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a vba script that would trigger various macros based on cell value change. For a single cell value change, the code below of 'C22' cell worked fine - but When I added additional cells, it's giving me an error.

Any thoughts?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Target.Address = "$C$22" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Yes"
            Call Hide280C
        Case "No"
            Call Show280C
        Case "Not Sure"
            Call Show280C
        Case ""
            Call Show280C
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select

If Target.Address = "$L$33" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Yes"
            Call NJCreditShow
        Case "No"
            Call NJCreditHide
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select

If Target.Address = "$L$34" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Yes"
            Call PACreditShow
        Case "No"
            Call PACreditHide
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `it's giving me an error` is not an information that can help us to help you. Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need a `End If` for each `If`, or in this case better use `ElseIf` statements. Have a look into the [VBA Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ifthenelse-statement) of `If … ElseIf … End If`.

Comment: you have 3 x `If` and only 1 `End If` - it's a problem

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$C$22" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Yes"
            'Call Hide280C (Call not needed)
            Hide280c
        Case "No"
            Show280C
        Case "Not Sure"
            Show280C
        Case ""
            Show280C
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
ElseIf Target.Address = "$L$33" Then 'You missed the End if, but you could also use ElseIf and only have one End if at the end.
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Yes"
            NJCreditShow
        Case "No"
            NJCreditHide
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
ElseIf Target.Address = "$L$34" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Yes"
            PACreditShow
        Case "No"
            PACreditHide
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Or, you can implement also a `Select Case Target.Address` . Also using `Call` is unecessary

Comment: @Xabier Just IMHO to get up-votes for an answer you should post good quality answers and write a bit more words than just a copy/paste ready solution. This site is more useful for understanding and learning if a solution provides the 'how' and 'why' instead of just code (which only make it easy to just copy/paste instead of thinking and learning something). According to the guidelines code only answers are bad quality answers and should be avoided.

Comment: @Peh, I wanted to answer the question, the OP made a simple omission on the End If part, as you and a couple of other people have already mentioned the omission, I thought my answer should be simplified, but I understand what you are trying to say and I will aim to elaborate and comment more thoroughly to help people learn..

Comment: @Xabier no worries, I just think sometimes a short comment will force an OP to think more than posting the copy/paste answer which works without thinking at all.

Comment: @Xabier Thanks for your input - I appreciate it. However, the 2nd and 3rd macro triggers are not working when I change the value in those cells (i.e. L33 and L34) Yes, No, or [blank]. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Riz "*are not working*" is a useless error description as you can imagine. So you will need to learn how to debug a code now (there are tutorials for this). To give you a start: When you change those cells check (1) if the `Worksheet_Change` event is run at all (place a breakpoint at the first line). (2) check the value of `Target.Address` by `Debug.Print Target.Address`. (3) Place a breakpoint at the first line and debug the code step-by-step (with F8) to see what happens and which commands are triggered.